# Call settings.py variable while Celery task running

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I have a Django app, and need to add a Celery async tasks. I would like to call in the tasks a settings variable from dev.py for example MY_VARIABLE='test'. To simplified the example lets assume that there is my task:

```
from django.conf import settings

@shared_task
def test_task():
    return settings.MY_VARIABLE
```

my celery.py looks like

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings.dev')

app = Celery('proj')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

the dev.py looks like

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
# CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:mypass@myhost/postgres'

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
MY_VARIABLE='test'
```

While runing Celery worker via

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=proj.settings.dev
celery -A proj worker -l info
```

in the caller I run

```
res = test_task.delay(*args)
```

In the response in celery terminal I'm receiving AttributeError.

```
'Settings' object has no attribute 'MY_VARIABLE'
```

What I am doing wrong? And how properly can I call settings variable to the async task?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your celery.py look like

Comment: @iklinac I added celery.py to the Question

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not loading your **dev.py** file from Django setting. Your celery app and task code look indeed correct. IF you can paste the bit in your settings when you load **dev.py** that will be very helpful to help you.

Comment: I added dev.py content in to the Question.

Comment: yes but  **MY_VARIABLE** is not in your dev.py example, also, is your manage.py loading dev.py as your Django settings?

Comment: I modify my dev.py and launch my manage.py with DAJNGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=proj.settings.dev. The problem still occurs. My Django version is 1.11 and Celery is 4.0.2

Comment: does **proj/settings** have an **__init__.py** file?

Comment: Also, try upgrading Celery to 4.1.0 , i used 4.0.2 for a project and was buggy

Comment: yes, proj/settings has __init__.py file. About Celery 4.1.0 I will test it at dev tomorrow

Comment: it seems, that upgrading Celery has no affect at my error. Tried also test my task at the caller, but without async 'delay' function - in that test the setting variables are visible...